# java check time is greater time

Tags: java, time, java-7

Hi I'm trying to check if the currentime is > , say, 14:00.  Does anyone know how to do this?

This is what I have:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm");
```

Somehow I guess I need to now create a Date object and use this dateformat?

I know the current time is:

```
date= new Date();
```

and in the above format it would be return `dateFormat.format(date);`

So can anyone help - much appreciated. (am using Java 7 btw)

Answer (score 9):

Try below code, it should work.

```
Date date = new Date() ;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm") ;
dateFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

if(dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date)).after(dateFormat.parse("12:07")))
{
    System.out.println("Current time is greater than 12.07");
}else{
    System.out.println("Current time is less than 12.07");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using Gregorian Calendar hope this helps ;)

```
public Class Time {

    public static void main() {

        Calendar C = new GregorianCalendar();
        int hour = C.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY );
        int minute = C.get( Calendar.MINUTE );

        if( hour == 14 && minute > 0 )
            System.out.println("time > 14");
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Date.compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29):

```
Date now = new Date();
Date date = dateFormat.parse(...);
if( now.compareTo( date) < 0 ) {
    ... date is in the future ...
}
```

But note that java.util.Date and all related classes have many quirks and subtle bugs. You will make your life much easier by using [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime date = dateFormat.parse(...); // see http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Input_and_Output
if( now.isBefore(date) ) {
    ... date is in the future ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if one date is earlier than another you could use Calendar.

```
Date yourDate                 = new Date();
Date yourDateToCompareAgainst = new Date();
Calendar calendar             = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(yourDateToCompareAgainst);
calendar.set(HOUR, 14);

/** You can then check for your condition */
if( calendar.before(yourDate) ) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Calendar from java.util to achieve this. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date date = new Date();        
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
    if(date.after(dateFormat.parse("14:00"))){
        System.out.println("Current time greater than 14.00");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This Function check string times (12:00:10 > 12:00:00 etc...)

```
public static boolean biggerThanTime(String time1,String time2){
    String hhmmss1[] = time1.split(":");
    String hhmmss2[] = time2.split(":");
    for (int i = 0; i < hhmmss1.length; i++) {
        if(Integer.parseInt(hhmmss1[i])>Integer.parseInt(hhmmss2[i]))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> to check whether the time is greater than present time

```
import java.util.*;
import java.time.*;
class one_part
{
public static void main(String []args)
{
LocalTime present=LocalTime.now();
String bf1="07:00:00";
String bf2="10:30:00";
LocalTime bf3 = LocalTime.parse(bf1);
LocalTime bf4 = LocalTime.parse(bf2);
String lunch1="11:30:00";
String lunch2="15:00:00";
LocalTime lunch3=LocalTime.parse(lunch1);
LocalTime lunch4=LocalTime.parse(lunch2);
String dinner1="19:30:00";
String dinner2="22:30:00";
LocalTime dinner3=LocalTime.parse(dinner1);
LocalTime dinner4=LocalTime.parse(dinner2);
if(present.isAfter(bf3) && present.isBefore(bf4))
{
System.out.println("this is breakfast time");
}
else if(present.isAfter(lunch3) && present.isBefore(lunch4))
{
    System.out.println("This is lunch time");
}
else if(present.isAfter(dinner3) && present.isBefore(dinner4))
{
    System.out.println("This is dinner time");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Restaurent closed");
}
}
}
```

Comment: posts at Stackoverflow usually pretend to ask questions for a problem you are having. There is no question here, would you be able to elaborate what your problem is?