# Check the time which is greater than the given time

Tags: java

I'm trying to find  whether the input time is greater than particular time.For eg check whether the time given by the user is greater than 9:30 if yes means return true or else return false.I want this in java. I don't how to start.I don't have any idea about this.Can anyone tell me how can i do this?

Comment: Convert them to `DateTime` and compare them.

Comment: You can use just Date type for it, and compare will perform by after method. Some examples can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186680/java-check-time-is-greater-time

Answer (score 1):

If you are using at least Java 8, you can use the java.time api and look at the localTime class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html

This will allow you to create a localTime object and compare different times.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

split the hour value and minute value,
you have to take care of time format (12 hr OR 24 hr) also.
get value as string and split like this. you have to convert to int values  here im taking as 24 hr

```
int a = 11; //hour given by user
int b = 30; //minute giver by user
int h  = 9; //default
int m = 30; //default

if( a > h){
    //
}else{
   if(a==h && b > m){
       //
    }
}
```

if you want to compare time with date, then  convert the datetime to timestamp which is long value like 15324242342
using this value of two datetime value you can get result.

Comment: The time should be get like this "11:30" and it compare with the time "9:30" in this format.So how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
return LocalTime.parse( "18:37" ).isAfter( LocalTime.of( 9 , 30 )  ) ;
```

## *java.time*

The [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) class represents a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone.

Define your threshold.

```
LocalTime limit = LocalTime.of( 9 , 30 ) ;
```

Gather input from user.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "18:37" ) ;
```

Compare.

```
boolean isLate = lt.isAfter( limit ) ;
```